# Error boundaries vs errorElement from react-router-dom package

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning how to use `react-router-dom` now. I have just encountered `errorElement` prop in `createBrowserRouter` function, I totally understand how `errorElement` prop works but I can't understand when I should choose error boundaries instead of `errorElement`. They can perform the same task, but what should I use more and why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the docs, the [`errorElement`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/error-element):

> `errorElement`
>
> When exceptions are thrown in [loaders](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader), [actions](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/action), or component
> rendering, instead of the normal render path for your Routes (`<Route element>`), the error path will be rendered (`<Route errorElement>`)
> and the error made available with [`useRouteError`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-route-error).
>
> This feature only works if using a data router like
> [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router)

The `Route` component's `errorElement` is useful for the specific occasions an error is thrown during processing a route's loader or action functions or when rendering the routed component and you can render more specific and useful UI whereas the regular React [error boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) are more for unexpected errors. You can narrow the scope of a React error boundary to display specific UI, but the benefit of the `errorElement` is the easier to use API abstraction. You don't need to implement the catch/handling logic yourself in a custom error boundary component (*React class component only*), but rather you can use the `useRouteError` hook to access the error that was thrown and you can focus more on the UI.

If you are working with `react-router` data routers and routes, and route loaders and actions, then using the `errorElement` seems the rather clear & obvious choice.